# C++ code translation and explanation

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following c++ code snippet. I have a basic understanding of c++ code.Please correct my explanation of the following code where ever necessary:

```
for (p = q->prnmsk, s = savedx->msk, j = sizeof(q->prnmsk);
           j && !(*p & *s); j--, p++, s++);
```

What does it contain: q is char *q(as declared) is type of structure MSK as per code.
                      q->prnmsk contains byte data where prnmask containd 15 bytes.

It is similar for s. 
So in the for loop as j decreases it will go through each byte and perform this `!(*p & *s)` operation to continue the loop and eventually if the condition is not met the loop will exit else j will run till j==0.

Am I correct? What does *p and *s mean? Will it contain the byte value?

Comment: could you please provide code with all variable declarations?

Comment: if p is a pointer, then *p is the object indicated by that pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some (like me) might think that following is more readable

```
int j;
for (j = 0; j < sizeof(q->prnmsk); ++j)
{
  if ((q->prnmsk[j] & savedx->msk[j]) != 0) break;
}
```

which would mean that q->prnmsk and savedx->msk are iterated to find the first occurence of where bit-anding both is not zero.  if j equals sizeof(q->prnmsk), all bit-andings were zero.

Comment: Thanks I also thought the same. The code in the question was confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. `!(*p & *s)` means that they want to check if `q->prnmsk` and `savedx->msk` don't have corresponding bits set to `1` simultaneously.